# IOS Universal Links or URL Scheme to share informations between applications

Tags: ios, redirect, keychain, url-scheme, ios-universal-links

I try to share information between severals applications.

I know the limitation of keychains ("You cannot directly share any resources; every app is in its own "sandbox" and cannot access the resources of any any other app."), it's impossible to do the same behavior between 2 app with differents developper team...

I was looking for information about Universal link or url scheme, because you can add parameter in both of them.

I know that the common use is to redirect from a url website to an app, but is there a way to use redirection to do something like :

appA -> website url -> appB

- the user is automaticaly redirect from appA to appB, the website has no interface, it's only a redirection
  -appA and appB are 2 apps from different developper, but are always installed on the device. 
  -I have access to the website, and I can upload anything (apple app site associatrion file or anything else)

Comment: With [url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) you can share data within apps w/o browser interface. E.G. you can open google map from your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods to achieve data sharing between app.

If you own both of the apps use this:

1) App Groups -  An app group creates a secure container that multiple processes can access.

a) first Enable "App Groups" from your developer account.
Generate Provisioning profile. And enable app group sharing in both projects in xcode

b) In first app, save the data:

```
NSUserDefaults *dataContainer = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"com.xxx.appgroupid"];
[dataContainer setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"];
```

In second app, retrieve the data:

```
NSUserDefaults *dataContainer = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"com.xxx.appgroupid"];
NSLog(@"My value for key: %@",[dataContainer objectForKey:@"bar"]);
```

Comment: App group only shares data between apps when developer profile also be same.

Comment: Yes you are right indeed. So means it's different developer profile? What kind of data are you sharing by the way?

Comment: Like you created app from your profile and I created app from my profile. Now OP wants to share the data in these two apps. In these scenario group ID of one developer cant be shred with the other developer.

Comment: what is OP and what kind of data are you sharing? (string, image?)

Comment: My main goal is to share string, like juste a boolean true/false. My appA has a switch on/off, and my appB should receive this value to display a content or not.
And like @dahiya_boy said, 2 app are develop by different developer team (not same  group ID)

Comment: @gamerounet Why you'r using different profiles? Why not 2 apps in 1 profile? If you use one profile then you can do this -> https://github.com/dagostini/BBPortal

Comment: The main reason is that I will develop the application with the switch, and other application are already on store,and developped by clients. And these client want to communicate with my app to get the boolean value

Comment: Since you don't own the other app. Why not just call an API from the cloud/database instead of passing the boolean locally?

Comment: The main reason is I can't because of RGPD : If I do this, I have to save a tuple "device id/boolean value", and it's forbidden to stock any source of identity

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, because for universal links, config file need to place at server root. You can place the file at your server, but another application will not recognize the config at your server.

For universal links, there need to do some config at mobile application code. You can't do these on other vendor applications.

- Alternate option is Url Scheme:

For communication with other applications. Source application must know the recipient application url scheme, that requires to communicate via url schemes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: So you think it could be possible to use url scheme to communicate from:
APP A -> url that redirect automaticly to APP B -> APP B ?

Comment: Like if you want to open mail application, you can use mailto:support@abc.com
To open phone application, tel://743234028